# sorting a LinkedHashset by date time

Tags: java, sorting, linkedhashset

I have the following LinkedHashset

It is as LinkedHashset because i have many duplicate entries upon addition and it prevents this.

How can i then sort my LinkedHashset

```
LinkedHashSet<String> uniqueStrings = new LinkedHashSet<>();

uniqueStrings.add("03/03/2016  00:00:00");
uniqueStrings.add("03/03/2016  00:30:00");
uniqueStrings.add("03/03/2016  01:00:00");
uniqueStrings.add("03/03/2016  00:30:00");
uniqueStrings.add("03/03/2016  00:01:00");



List<String> asList = new ArrayList<>(uniqueStrings);
System.out.println((asList+ "\n"));
```

Comment: Why LinkedHashSet rather than a TreeSet with date-time based Comparator?

Comment: Can i use a TreeSet to eliminate duplicates at entry?

Comment: yes, sets eliminate duplicates.

Comment: See the API documentation for [TreeSet's add](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#add-E-) method: "Adds the specified element to this set if it is not already present.". More simply, it implements Set and conforms to the Set contract.

Comment: Nice so all i need to do is change it to    TreeSet<String> uniqueStrings = new TreeSet(); and it will add non duplicates and sort the date time entries

Comment: You mentioned a date-time comparator will i need this?

Comment: You also need a proper `Comparator` implementation for defining the wished-for ordering.

Comment: Im not sure how to do that, what can i read to help?

Comment: also currently i have the LinkedHashset as a String is that right, if i am going to create a comparator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a TreeSet with a comparator that parses text to Date.

```
private static Date safeParse(DateFormat dateFormat, String str) {
    try {
        return dateFormat.parse(str);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    Comparator<String> comparator = (a, b) -> safeParse(format, a).compareTo(safeParse(format, b));

    Set<String> uniqueStrings = new TreeSet<>(comparator);

    uniqueStrings.add("03/03/2016  00:00:00");
    uniqueStrings.add("03/03/2016  00:30:00");
    uniqueStrings.add("03/03/2016  01:00:00");
    uniqueStrings.add("03/03/2016  00:30:00");
    uniqueStrings.add("03/03/2016  00:01:00");

    uniqueStrings.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
}
```